# What is one way to copy and paste on a docs?

Tags: google-docs

I can't copy or paste on google docs It just won't work it keeps saying I have to download an app to do it but I can't my school chrome won't let me it says the app is blocked what do I do?

Answer (score 0):

sry it's me again I already know the answer it is used to press ctrl-c to copy and press ctrl-v to paste just so others with the same question can see this one and know the anwser.